# How to return the value when Observable is complete?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I've made this Observable to compress Bitmap:

```
public static Uri compressBitmapInBackground(Bitmap original, Context context)
{
    Uri value;
    Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Uri>) e ->
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),decoded, "Title", null);
        Log.d("pathCompress",path);
        Uri uriPath = Uri.parse(path);

        e.onNext(uriPath);
        e.onComplete();
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(x-> System.out.print(x) );


    //how to return x when observable is complete? 
}
```

my problem is that I want to return the result when the Observable is completed: is there a way to do it? Because I could call the presenter from my function on the onNext() but I prefer to avoid it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing concerns. I'd split the concepts into:

```
public static Uri compressBitmap(Bitmap original, Context context) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
  Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
  String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),decoded, "Title", null);
  Log.d("pathCompress",path);
  Uri uriPath = Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Then just use this method in the observable flow:

```
Observable
.from(...)
.map(foo -> getBitmap(bar))
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.map(bitmap -> compressBitmap(bitmap,context))
.doOnNext(url -> dowhatever(url))
```

This way, you have a single method that does a single thing (compress bitmap), and you can use it in the observable chain without getting lost in the details or switching threads a ton of times.

Comment: interesting...I've made the last code only for make reusable code, but I could only reuse the function and implement the Observable in each class I need, sure?

Comment: Exactly - and because in each case there's different needs in place (how many bitmaps to compress vs how often to update the display, online/offline/background processing etc), it's usually better to make self-contained processes, and then tie them together in each location where you need to use them.